# WSO2 IS Role of Facebook user in SAML response

Tags: spring, facebook, wso2, spring-saml, wso2-identity-server

I'm using Spring Security SAML with WSO2 IS. When I login with Facebook and get SAML response from WSO2 IS in my application I haven't role attribute in Authentication object.

For example, when I login with basic auth, then I have role attribute :|

Claims in Service Provider are configured like below:

[image: Claims]

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Did you do a claim mapping for 'role' attribute the IDP representing facebook?

Comment: @farasath, solved.

Comment: was this issue only solved after you added the entry manually?

Comment: @farasath, yes. `JDBCUserStoreManager` get roles from table `um_user_role`, where was not relation records between user and roles for Facebook users :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have connected custom PostgreSQL user store and for some reason in table `um_user_role` I haven't relation between role and Facebook user, but in `carbon IS` it is. :\

When I added relation manually into this table all works fine.